# Why this setState call does not trigger rendering?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have made a small treeview component, which gets a json file with the structure and should render the treeview.

The json is correct, the promise on the constructor is resolved correctly, but the render is not called after the setState inside the constructor.

I´ve tried to read similar questions, but no success.

```
export default class Tree extends Component<ITreeProps, ITreeState> {

    public constructor(props: ITreeProps, state: ITreeState) {
        super(props, state);

        Tree.GetJsonStructure(props.Path).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                data : JSON.parse(response)               
            });
            console.log(response);
          });          
    }

    public static GetJsonStructure(jsonPath: string): Promise<string>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios.get(jsonPath, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
              // handle error
              reject("FAIL!");
            }
            var buf = new Buffer(response.data);
            //var buf = Buffer.concat(response.data);
            var paki = pako.inflate(buf);
            var decoder = new encoding.TextDecoder();
            var stringo = decoder.decode(paki);
            resolve(stringo);
          });
        });
      }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<ITreeProps> {
        console.log("RENDERINGGGG");
        console.log(this.state)

        if(!this.state || !this.state.data || this.state.data.length == 0 ){
            return <div></div>;
        }

        const data = this.state.data;

        if (!data || data.length == 0) 
            console.log("No properties set for the application");

        return (
          <div className={styles.ToolboxLinkPanel}>
              {
                  data.map(node => (
                      <TreeNode key={node.key} label={node.label} children={node.nodes} isOpen={true} ></TreeNode>
                  ))
              }
          </div>
        );
      }
}
```

Comment: Try using `await this.setState()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call your api method inside `componentDidMount` and not in the constructor:

```
componentDidMount() {
  Tree.GetJsonStructure(props.Path).then(response => {
    this.setState({
      data: JSON.parse(response)
    });
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

As to why it's the place to make api calls, the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) elaborates (emphasis added):

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM
>   nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint,
>   **this is a good place to instantiate the network request** [...] It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen..

Comment: yea do this, calling set state in a constructor is probably a bad idea as the component isn't mounted yet so who knows what even happens under the hood when you try to do that. any async code like that should be moved to a lifecycle function rather than the constuctor, you should only initialize state in the constructor if you already know what it is before hand like `this.state = { ... }`

Comment: That´s absolutely right! Could you please elaborate on the why it doesn't work in the constructor but only in the componentDidMount event?

Comment: It's because there the component gets instantiated. After rendering the component a lifecycle method componentDidMount gets called. That's the indication for each component, that it is mounted (and inserted into the tree). You can read about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount tl;dr: Why? It's a design "choice" of React when to handle side-effects like API calls etc.

Comment: @GabrielMarcondes updated the answer. As to why it doesn't work in constructor I'd assume that calling `setState` there, after an async request has been completed, won't trigger a rerender.

Comment: Thanks Clarity, and @r3dst0rm, your comments are appreciated.